# Minesweeper-style matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I posted this question on the puzzling SE but it might as well have its place here.

The premise is simple. We get a n*n matrix with numbers ranging from 0 to 16. The matrix is the result of a minesweeper-kind of addition whereby we have an original matrix containing numbers ranging from 0 to 3 and the second matrix is none else than the sum of the surrounding cells od the first matrix, wrapping around (i.e. $c_{0\_0}$ =  $c_{0\_1}$ +  $c_{1\_1}$  $c_{1\_0}$ +  $c_{1,2\_0}$ +  $c_{0\_2}$ +  $c_{2\_2}$ +  $c_{0\_0}$ +  $c_{2\_0}$

Example:

```
1 2 3
0 1 3
3 2 1
```

yields

```
15 14 13
16 15 13
13 14 15
```

How would you go about solving this mathematically for squares of arbitrary size 0 <= n < 100?

To clarify: the goal is to get the original matrix (shown first, containing only $0,1,2,3$) from the second matrix.

Edit: another example:

```
0 0 1
1 0 0 
0 1 2
```

yields

```
5 5 4
4 5 5
5 4 3
```

```

Comment: Solving? For what?

Comment: You want to get the original matrix (shown first) from the second matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The operation is not invertible, for matrices of size $2n \times 2n$ (at least), e.g.

$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2 & 2 & 2\\\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2\\\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2\\\
2 & 2 & 2 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

and

$\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\\
1 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\\
3 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\\
1 & 3 & 1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$

end up in the same matrix
$\begin{pmatrix}
16 & 16 & 16 & 16 \\\
16 & 16 & 16 & 16 \\\
16 & 16 & 16 & 16 \\\
16 & 16 & 16 & 16
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: The OP asked for $0 \leq n \leq 100$, probably, all even $n$s counter-example answers at least half :-)

Comment: OK fair enough, it makes sense. However, how would I go about to reverse it? We assume that the matrix is solvable (at least 1 valid solution)

Answer (score 1):

Let the total of the entries in the original be $T$. It is easy to check that an entry $x$ in the original becomes $T-x$. So the new total is $8T$.

So to recover the original, find the new total, divide by 8 to get $T$. Then subtract each entry from $T$ to get the original.

Take the first example in the Q. The sum of the entries is 128. Divide by 8 to get 16. Now subtract each entry from 16 to get the original. Similarly for the second example in the Q.

---

To answer the comment below: no, it won't work for larger matrices. The special feature of the $3\times3$ is that all the other entries surround each one.

@dEmigOd has provided an elegant proof that there is no inverse map for even $n>2$ and @stuart stevenson has dealt with $n=2$. So the **outstanding problem is odd** $\mathbf{n>3}$.

Note that we can regard the matrices as finite-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$. The the map from original to derived is linear, so if we can prove that the map is not surjective, then it cannot be injective. So one approach would be to show that we cannot produce the matrix with all entries 0 except one (whatever real values we use for the original matrix).

Comment: could you add an example? And does it work for arbitrary n*n matrices?

Comment: Regarding the linearity, I have doubts. in the even case, only one matrix is mapped to 0. Though there is a multiple pre-image to some matrices. And there is a condition on which matrices are in space. Nor you can add matrices!

Comment: @dEmigOd You just regard them as points in  $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.

Comment: Ok, then it is obvious we can't produce matrices whose total sum of elements is not divisible by $8$. But why does it help? $f(x) = 2x$ let say on $\mathbb{Z}$ is injective and not surjective.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done for unique solutions.

`2 2
2 2`

can derive from 

`1 0
0 1`

and

`0 1
1 0`

Any integer programming software could help you find a feasible solution but it's not necessarily going to be unique or have a solution at all.

Comment: @almagest The Q asks about $n \times n$ for $0 \leq n \leq 100$.